# Django allauth send email verification code instead of email verification link

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, email-verification

I am using Django allauth as an API for a mobile application. Currently, when you register Django will send you an email containing a link which you have to go to in order to verify your email. But what if I want to make it so that Django send an email with a verification code which you then enter into the app? I know it seems kind of redundant but I think it will help streamline the user experience (since my platform will primarly have an app).

Is this possible to do?